# Python Pygal: Setting serie color

Tags: python, bar-chart, pygal

I am trying set the color of all the elements in a serie of values. Checking the documentation I have found a way of accomplish it. By this way I have to specify the color of every element, like this:

```
key = "Power"
power_values = [{'value' : 1.0, 'color' : 'red'},{'value' : 3.0, 'color' : 'red'},{'value' : 5.0, 'color' : 'red'},{'value' : 8.0, 'color' : 'red'}]

bar_chart.add(key, power_values)
```

This works fine, but I am looking for a one-step way, so I could set the color once, and not once for every element in the value list. I tried this:

```
key = "Power"
power_values = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0]
bar_chart.add(key, power_values, color="red")
```

But it doesn't work I am sure that it may exists a similar way to do it.

Someone could help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/custom_styles.html) has pygal style examples that could help.

Would this work for you?

```
import pygal
from pygal.style import Style

power_values = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0]
key = 'Power'
red = Style(colors=('red',))
bar_chart = pygal.Bar(style=red)
bar_chart.add(key, power_values)
```